# How do I import a local module in a Mako template?

Tags: python, import, module, local, mako

Suppose we have a local python module in the same directory as a mako template: `./my_template.mako ./my_module/module.py`

How do I import that module into a Mako template that is supposed to be rendered from the command line using mako-render? The following does not work:

```
<%! import my_module.module %>
```

It seems that the local path is not part of the search path. However, putting each custom module into the global path is not an option.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that you are missing the `__init__.py` in your ./my_module folder that is required for my_module to be a package.  This file can be left empty, it just needs to be present to create the package.

Here is a working example doing what you describe.

**Directory Layout**

```
.
├── example.py
├── my_module
│   ├── __init__.py    <----- You are probably missing this.
│   └── module.py
└── my_template.mako
```

**Files**

example.py

```
from mako.template import Template
print Template(filename='my_template.mako').render()
```

my_template.mako

```
<%! import my_module.module %>
${my_module.module.foo()}
```

module.py

```
def foo():
    return '42'
```

__init__.py

```
# Empty
```

**Running the Example**

```
>> python example.py

42
```

Answer (score 0):

mako-render lives in /usr/local/bin or some path like that.

It is a python script and follows the python interpreter's rules to look for import modules in:
 1. its directory (/usr/local/bin)
 2. the PYTHONPATH environment variable
 3. In the installation libraries.

you can get this working by doing:

$ env PYTHONPATH=. mako-render